# How do I calculate year over year population growth in powerBI

Tags: dax

I am new to Power BI,

I have a sample dataset of the 50 States with their population for years from 2012 to 2022.

I want to calculate the Year-over-year population growth for each State. Looking for ideas on how to do this.

|
| State    | Year     | Population |
| -------- | -------- | -----------
| Alabama  |2012      | 5000
| Alaska    2012        200
|Alabama    2013        5500
|Alaska     2013        350

I am not sure on how to proceed and need some advice.

Comment: What did you try? Something with CALCULATE( MIN([Population]),'Table'[Year]=MAX('table'[Year])-1) && [State] = MAX('table'[State]) )

Comment: I will try that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it really depends on what you want to show. If you just want to show YoY for each state. It can be as easy as putting the 3 columns in a matrix and call it a day:
[image]

If you want it to be more interactive you can add a year Slicer and write a measures like this:

```
Population SY = 
CALCULATE( SUM('Table'[Population]) )

Population PY =
CALCUALTE( SUM('Table'[Population]), SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DIM_DATE[DATE]) )

Population ∆ = [Population SY] - [Population PY]

Population ∆% = DIVIDE([Population SY], [Population PY] )
```

These measures can be added into (almost) every visual and show the same result. Below are some examples:

- A map with the states that are colorcoded by the YoY population growth using conditional formatting.
- A line/ bar chart showing the population between 2012 and 2022 for a given state based on a slicer selection. (With multiple select turned on so you can compare two or more states with eachother)
- A scatterchart to show if the largest states by population grow/ shrink the most. (By absolute or % values)